# Phrase expressing a positive future or destiny

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests, idioms

A French friend of mine is looking for an phrase or expression (for a tatoo...) that expresses optimism for the future.  The idea that anything can happen but that she's hopeful that things will be positive.  With a sense of nothing being set in stone.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to use that same cliché "set in stone," and play on it, you'd end up with something related to:

> **"The only thing I have set in stone is uncertainty."**

It might not be as positive as you wanted, but it does have traces of boldness and bravery for the unknown.

Additional cliché play might give you the results of:

> **"Fact of life: There aren't any."**
>
> **"A walk of life wears shoes of unknowing hope."**

To my knowledge, these are original quotes, but there's always a chance someone else said them. I could, and possibly am, be entirely missing the mark with what you're after, but these are just ideas that could hopefully guide you to what you need.

Comment: Actually there are facts of life, **death and taxes,** and those were [first recognised in 1716](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_and_taxes_(idiom)). Since both had been around for ages before that, I wonder why it took so long.

Comment: I think "Aside from death and taxes, for obvious reasons, there aren't any facts of life." makes for a long tattoo. Ha.

Comment: Thank you, André, for the research and ideas.  Not a tatoo person myself and I don't know which part of the person is going to be tatoo'd (tatood/tatooed?) but I shall suggest both.

Answer (score 0):

Although mostly used as a form of farewell or good-bye, sailors often wish each other "fair winds and following seas."  The implication is of a boat or ship running before the weather, being comfortably propelled forward, and not pounding into waves- of being swiftly and safely carried on to the destination.

Whether this works for your friend or his/her tattoo depends on that person's affinity for sailing and the sea, which I cannot know.  However, it is clear that [others are doing it.](https://www.google.com/search?q=fair%20winds%20and%20following%20seas%20tattoo&espv=2&site=webhp&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwiq3czNjurSAhVG7SYKHQXJBN4Q_AUIBigB&biw=1920&bih=901#imgrc=_)

Comment: Oh my (the pictures)!  Rather her than me!  Thank you for your input.